# merge string list with integer list

Tags: python

I am trying to merge  list 1 with list 2
list 1= [1,3,4,6,7]
list 2 = [a,b,c,d,e]

output List = [[1,a],[3,b],[4,c],[6,d],[7,e]]

```
def merge(list 1, list 2):
    return [a + b for (a, b) in zip(list 1, list 2)]

print(merge(list 1, list 2))
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please, remember to [read the posting guidelines](/help/how-to-ask): your post doesn't have a question, so there is nothing for anyone to help with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to turn `1` and `a` into `[1, a]`, then you should turn `a` and `b` into `[a, b]` rather than `a + b`:

```
[[a, b] for a, b in zip(list1, list2)]
```

To convert the tuples generated by `zip` into lists you can also `map` them to the `list` constructor:

```
list(map(list, zip(list1, list2)))
```